# Flask Azure Webapp AADSTS50011: The redirect URI '<url>/getAToken' returning http instead of https

Tags: python-3.x, flask, azure-web-app-service, redirect-uri-mismatch

I followed the microsoft code for flask application. Localhost went well however to change the version in production, even inserting the redirect url as https, the application insists on sending http and the error occurs.

[image: error]

I noticed that in github actions, the final URL is http, even putting the `ssl_context = 'adhoc'` on `app.run` command.

I don't know if it's possible to force https on github actions.

Reinforcing: localhost all went well. But Azure accepts http://localhost and nothing more.

Please help!

[redirect uri print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjCjG.png)

[github actions print 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCRuT.png)

[github actions print 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoMLb.png)

Comment: Could you please provide me the screenshot of the Redirect URI which you have given in the Azure Active Directory ?

Comment: Sure! It's in the question now.

Comment: How you are requesting the URL? Check whether you have https mentioned in the request or not

Comment: I don't have that possibility. I just point the route to the redirect uri (/getAToken). I think maybe the problem persists on github actions pipeline...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- As mentioned in this [Document](https://flask-dance.readthedocs.io/en/v0.13.0/proxies.html)

> we can just inform Flask that it is running behind a proxy.
> wrap your application with Werkzueg’s `ProxyFix` middleware
>
> ```cs
> from flask import Flask
> from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix
>
> app = Flask(__name__)
> app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
> ```

- With the help of this , Flask will learn how to make sure whether a request was truly made using `HTTP` or `HTTPS`.
- Also refer @[rayluo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp/issues/18#issuecomment-604744997) comment in GitHub

Please refer [Proxy Setups](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#proxy-setups) for more information

Comment: It WORKED! Updated app with the ProxyFix